# AppSearch configuration doesn't have index name in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, app-search

I'm a newbie installing elasticsearch and app search on AWS ec2. I got elastic search working on an Ubuntu instance and I can add documents to it using Postman locally. Then I installed app-search on a local VMWare Linux instance (I can't get it working on AWS unfortunately, but that's a problem for another day) and pointed it to the elasticsearch server and I can add documents here as well. But Postman and App Search are using two different indexes and the docs I add in Postman aren't showing up in the App search application. How do I tell app-search which index to use so it shares documents with Postman? I don't see a setting anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to tech support and they said this can't be done. AppSearch creates a default index when it starts and that is the only one it can reference. For an existing index and you have to bring your documents into the default one created by AppSearch.